# How do I fill in my half circles?

Tags: c#, drawing

I am trying to fill in my two half circles. I want one side black and the other side white. What do I use?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 320, 320);
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10), rect, 90, 180);
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 10), rect, 270, 180);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

What you expect to be called `FillArc` is actually called [`FillPie`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It takes the same parameters as `DrawArc`, so this will do:

```
e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.White, rect, 90, 180);
e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Black, rect, 270, 180);
```

If you want to use the same rectangle you can 'deflate' it by 1/2 the pen width:

```
rect.Inflate(-5, -5);
```

Using

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

you get this:

[image]

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for and I had the same question as the OP. This is the answer. Why didn't OP set this as answer?  Thanks.